# Server ignoring subdirectory htaccess file, going straight to root htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an application that utilizes Codeigniter and SLIR (Smart Lencioni Image Resizer https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR). SLIR allows you to resize images using an intuitive URI structure. For example:

```
<img src="/slir/w100-h100/path/to/image.jpg"/>
```

This would resize the image to fit 100px * 100px. For whatever reason when I try to view a resized image, (eg. http://a2op03.com/slir/w300-h90/images/content/franchise-opportunities-badge.png) I am getting a 404 error generated by Codeigniter. I have verified the following:

- http://a2op03.com/images/content/franchise-opportunities-badge.png does exist.
- According to the host mod_rewrite is setup properly and working.
- GD Library (for SLIR) is setup and enabled
- According to SLIR, everything is setup properly (http://a2op03.com/slir/install/)

The Codeigniter [root] htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

and the htaccess file in /slir/ looks like this:

```
# Prevent other scripts from interfering with SLIR
php_value auto_prepend_file none
php_value auto_append_file none

# Pretty URLs
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent viewing of the error log file in its default location
<Files slir-error-log>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```

My initial suspicion was that mod_rewrite.c was not setup properly and therefore was not being processed by the SLIR htaccess and falling back on the root htaccess which is sending it to a 404. I'm hosting on a managed VPS via servint.net and have WHM with full access to the server. The host claims that mod_rerwrite should be working fine. I have this working flawlessly on another server, but I can't figure out why it's not working here. Any helps is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I just needed to add

```
RewriteBase /slir/
```

After

```
RewriteEngine On
```

In SLIR's htaccess file!